# Add image file on Employee Screen and add it into Purchase Order report designer

Tags: acumatica

On Employee Screen (ScreenId=EP203000) I added the image file as signature. After Add it I want to display that signature of employees on Purchase Order form as owner and approval. 
Picture below is what I want but don't know how to get these pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already done it with the solution below:

1. Edit report POOrder (po641000.rpx)
2. Add more relationships

   - POOrder Join EPApproval (NoteID - RefNoteID)
   - EPApproval Join EPEmployee (ApprovalByID - UserID)
   - EPEmployee Join NoteDoc (NoteID - NoteID)
   - NoteDoc Join Note (NoteID - NoteID) : ApprovalSign
   - NoteDoc Join UploadFile (FileID - FileID)
   - POOrder Join EPEmployee (EmployeeID - BAccountID) : PrepareSign
3. Add Picture Box

   1. Approval Signature:

      Mime Type: image/png

      Source : Database

      Value : =[ApprovalSign.NoteText]
   2. Prepare Signature:

      Mime Type: image/png

      Source : Database

      Value : =[PrepareSign.NoteText]
   3. Result:

[image]