# How can i add an image to a Acumatica Report if i uploaded more than one image to a Stock Item?

Tags: image, report, acumatica

I've added four USR fields to the InventoryItem Table to save the ImageURL of the uploaded images to the Stock Item record, and I want to be able to add those images to a report but in different pages of the report, any help on how to do it?

this is what I have so far.

Page:
[Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBJ4u.png)

Report (1st Page):
[Report 1st page concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmHsZ.png)

Report (2nd Page):
[Report 2nd page concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKRiW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the help from Acumatica Dev support, it appears that the Usr fields I've previously added to the InventoryItem table were able to retrieve the images as they are linked to the images itself so the answer is the following: add as many Usr fields as images you want to add to the page, they (the images) are all linked to the same NoteID and you can show them at the report by setting the Data attributes as the following

```
MimeType: image/jpeg
source: Database
value: =IIf([InventoryItem.ImageURL] = Null, '', [InventoryItem.ImageURL])
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a logical pattern or set page on which each image shows, you could use VisibleExpr. This will hide the image(s) until the expression evaluates to true.

Comment: The report goes like this:

-I've made a group using the InventoryID to add a header section for some custom table I made

-In that header section, I've duplicated the section to set the "PageBreak" behavior to "BeforeAndAfter"

-I want to add the first image in the 1st header section and the other 4 images in the 2nd header section

Comment: Visible Expression could work here. You would need to set a flag to distinguish which header is which and show the images accordingly. You could also use page numbers. If this is the only header in the entire report, you could always show the single image when page = 1 and show the other images when page = 2.

Comment: but how does the report know which image is adding because I've added the data to the PictureBox in the 1st header like this... MimeType: image/jpeg, Source: Database and Value: =[InventoryItem.NoteFiles] and is not even showing the 1st image.

Comment: I believe you will need to link to the specific image you want in the UploadRevisionFile table.

Comment: With NoteFiles field you need to attach the image to the NoteID field. Either in UI or with FileUploadMaintenance class. With NoteFiles you have 1 image per record so you have to create a new child table specifically to store those images.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA I created 4 additional UsrFields in the table. The goal is to use those 4 fields so that a child table will not be needed (for simplification purposes). I then tried to use the NoteFiles field but nothing was printed. I used this other stackoverflow as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823828/add-image-file-on-employee-screen-and-add-it-into-purchase-order-report-designer.
I would like to show you this implementation in a screenshot but I do not think I am able to do it in a comment

Comment: You can edit your original post and post an image into the question.

Comment: @DanielMoncadaZ you can't mix both, the NoteFiles approach work but it needs 1 file per record attached to the NoteID. That you have UsrFields is irrelevant if you use NoteFiles.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA in the child table the images have to be stored the same as the NoteID field of the InventoryItem Table?, also I've customized the Stock Item page to add the images to that page as well, and finally I need to know how is this new table going to interact with the page customization?

Comment: You could use PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes to attach the files to NoteID of the child table.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA I updated the question so it shows clearly what I want to do, I don't know how to create the child table to make it all work as its shown in the images I've posted now, could you help me with that?