# Show Attached Image File on Report

Tags: acumatica

I need to print an image file on the Inventory Valuation report (IN615500) that is attached to an item.  How can I do this?

Version 19.101 of Acumatica.

I found this:

[Add image file on Employee Screen and add it into Purchase Order report designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823828/add-image-file-on-employee-screen-and-add-it-into-purchase-order-report-designer)

but, I'm just not following on how to do this.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with the hardcoded magic field name `NoteFiles`.

Add a picture box control, set properties Mime Type to `image/gif` Source to `Database` and Value to `=[InventoryItem.NoteFiles]`:
[image]

I tested this solution for Inventory Valuation report:
[image]

Comment: Sweet!  What if I want one specific image file on the item?  so, if it has 5 images attached, I'm needing one that is named the same for every item.

Comment: > What if I want one specific image file on the item? - You're screwed (kind of). It is 1 image per record and it takes the first one. So if you need multiple image you need to create a new table (ex: InventoryItemImage), join it to the inventory item with a X to 1 relationship and attach one image per record.

Comment: At least I can vouch for the feasibility of this solution, I did a successful implementation using that technique. You'll have to add the custom table to report schema builder, define relationship as left joins and maybe tweak the report to have the custom table as the detail items.

Comment: It is also possible to fetch the images by name but I find doing so inconvenient and less reliable. Report AR641000 use that method to display Company Branch logo. The value points to a DB field that contain the image name in a format similar to that found in page SM202520. The format looks something like this: "Branches (HQ        )\web-logo-(210x50-bg).svg"